# Rxjava takeWhen operator

Tags: rx-java

I was looking an rxjava operator which waits another observable emits an item to observe an item. I can do it with flatMap and map operators but I just wonder if there is an operator which does this job. I am looking for opposite of takeUntil operator. I also want it to buffer items while its waiting the other observable.

Answer (score 1):

The opposite of [`takeUntil`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/takeuntil.html) is [`skipUntil`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/skipuntil.html).

Comment: Thanks. That what i was looking for except I also want it to buffer these items until an item is observed from the other observable. I don't want them get skipped. Is it possible?